# Add ng-template Dynamically

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, ng-template

I want to add below content dynamically in HTML.

```
<ng-template #elseblock *ngIf="var">
    <h1>
        {{heading}}
    </h1>
</ng-template>
```

I am using below approch for this.

In app.component.ts file :

```
htmldata: any = `<ng-template #elseComponent *ngIf="var">
<h1>
  {{ heading }}
</h1>
```

`;

and in app.component.html

```
 <div [innerHTML]="htmldata"> </div>
```

but this approch only render h1 tag in the DOM.(no ng-template)

Please help me to add ng-template dynamically so that #else block, *ngIf will also work.

Comment: [**ngTemplateOutlet**](https://medium.com/michalcafe/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9) is good approach

Answer (score 1):

As Per My Understanding from your question, you want to do content projection.

you should use template outlet for this type of usecase.

```html
<ng-template #heading let-heading>
  <h1>
    {{heading}}
  </h1>
</ng-template>


<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="heading; context: ContextObj">
</ng-container>
```

official Angular doc [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

 or a great blog post on [ngTemplateOutlet](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/)